# SegFault on glCreateShader

Tags: opengl, go, glow

I'm using Go, the line causing the segfault is:

```
shader := gl.CreateShader(shaderType)
```

I'm basing my code on [this example from go-gl repo](https://github.com/go-gl/examples/tree/master/gl41core-cube), which was working, so `gl` seems to be fine.

Most of my googling pointed to C++ questions to which the answer was to enable `glewExperimental`, but the Go bindings for OpenGL were generated with [`GLOW`](https://github.com/go-gl/glow), which apparently circumvents `GLEW`.

I am initializing my glfw contetxt:

```
if err := glfw.Init(); err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("failed to initialize glfw:", err)
}
```

and the `gl` library:

```
// Initialize Glow
if err := gl.Init(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing?  Are there any principles I can use to track this down, i.e. "glCreateShader() Segfaults when XYZ occurs"?

Comment: I'm not familiar with go, but I'm sure that `glfwInit` does NOT create a context and does also NOT make a context current. Either you're not giving us the whole picture, or you're simply missing some important code. Unless you're using some means to create a window-less context (supposedly works on X based platforms and OpenGL ES using EGL), you will have to create a window using [glfwCreateWindow](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html). Afterwards you'll have to make the context that is simultaneously created current with `glfwMakeContextCurrent`. THEN you call `gl.Init`.

Comment: @thokra: Just for sake of completenes: It's perfectly possible to create a windowless context with windows GDI using a PBuffer. But doing so is quite a convoluted process; which is probably part of the reason, that it's not widely known.

Comment: @datenwolf: thanks for the input! :) off topic, but do you by any chance have some concrete example for that at hand? just curious how you would go about that.

Comment: @thokra: Indeed I have. This Gist at Github (https://gist.github.com/datenwolf/b107499683f5cbe9d347e0061be22351) is part of a hack I had to implement recently to support a CUDA worker thread updating data in a shared context of a Qt application. IMHO the OpenGL abstractions of Qt are too tight. Don't ask about what problem the `secondary_hglrc` pointer parameter solves (let's just say, that if you don't have it around you can crash the NVidia drivers).